# SQLite 3 UTF-8 can't get first character in PHP mojibake

Tags: php, sqlite, unicode

The problem seems banal. I've connected to a SQLite 3 database with both PDO and native driver from PHP and I'm trying to compare the first letter of a value with my custom predefined array of letters, and when I try to access the whole value of a field like this:

```
<?= $row['naziv_opstine'];?>
```

I get

```
Žitorađa
```

But when I try to access the string as an array or to display it using substr, like this:

```
<?= substr($row['naziv_opstine'],0,1);?>
<?= $row['naziv_opstine'][0];?>
```

I get mojibake:

```
�
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem, both DB and HTML have encoding set to UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UTF8, `Ž` will take more then one byte (only Latin-1 characters are single byte).

Consider using [mb_substr](http://www.php.net/manual/function.mb-substr.php):

```
<?= mb_substr($row['naziv_opstine'], 0, 1, 'UTF-8');?>
```